# Got error when passing array into call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, mysqli

It works if i use this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($pstmt, 'bind_param'), array('ss','abc','def'));
```

But it didn't work if i use this:

```
$arr = array('ss','abc','def');
call_user_func_array(array($pstmt, 'bind_param'), $arr);
```

Why....

Comment: mysqlis´ `bind_param` needs variable references, not values, to be passed. (You know, this would be a good opportunity to investigate PDO, which is all-around easier to use.)